# Finding error in LaTeX document on Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I was wondering if there was an easier way of finding an error in the LaTeX document written using Visual Code. Its sometimes the case that there would be an error, such as a missing $ or {} or something similar, and unlike TeXWorks, VS won't show the exact nature of the error. It could be that I am missing something in the output panel.

Comment: Have a look at your .log file. That's what texworks parses to you show you the (incomplete) error message. Start at the begin of the file and search for errors.

Comment: If you want a nicely formatted list of error messages, have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, i cannot find the .log file or a separate text file where errors are listed. Please advise.

Comment: The .log file should normally be in the same folder as your .tex file